# Firebase Database (RDS or Firestore)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a small game backend and was considering to use Firebase db (RDS or Firestore).

I am a newbie in DBs and was wondering what is the best way to implement the "buy item" scenario in these databases and which one is better suited for this.

My `/BuyItem` endpoint basically does next:

1. Query user's balance
2. Check if balance >= item price
3. Decrease balance
4. Add item count to user inventory table

How to ensure that on step 3 user balance is still as it was on step 1? And it wasn't concurrently modified.

Comment: use firestore for that

Comment: @PeterHaddad  how can I guarantee that value didn't change before I update it using Firestore's transactions?

Comment: You'll read the value in the transaction before updating it. The Firestore transaction then makes sure that the value is unmodified.